# behavior of memset

Tags: c++

Does this function has the same behavior that `memset`?

```
inline void SetZeroArray( void *vArray[], unsigned int uArraySize )
{
       for(unsigned i=0; i<=uArraySize; i++ )
                    vArray[i] = NULL;
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{

        unsigned int uLevels[500];
        SetZeroArray( (void**)uLevels, 500 );

        unsigned int ulRLevels[500];
        memset( &ulRLevels, 0, sizeof( ulRLevels ) );


    system("pause>nul");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: What would the purpose of this function be when `memset` is already available?

Comment: Well, for one, it takes a different set of arguments, so no.

Comment: I suppose the downvotes are because this isn't generally useful.

Comment: In any case, memset can do architecture specific things related to cache behavior and alignment such that no user implemented equivalent would likely be as fast.  The only reason I can think of to roll your own is if you *can't* for some reason link in the standard library functions.

Comment: `i<=uArraySize` is an off by one error, you want `i < uArraySize` instead.

Comment: A decent compiler, like mine, will optimize the for() loop into the same code that memset generates.  REP STOS on an x86 core.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NO, your function does not behave the same as `memset`.  Your function sets a pointer to NULL and `memset` sets the values of the data to *the value supplied.*

Different things altogether.

Comment: Specially since the _bit-pattern_ for a null pointer is not required by the standard to be all _0s_.

Comment: also SetZeroArray is quite likely to result in undefined behavior, and does so in the example program.

Comment: `memset` sets the values to whatever the second parameter is.